# Obtaining generic key_type from C++ STL collections

Tags: c++, templates, stl, dictionary, set

I came up with the following code which demonstrates a technique for iterating generically over an STL collection and obtaining the key value regardless of how the key is stored.

The context of this is that I am refactoring two functions which both operate the same functionality on two collections: one is a `set<int>` and the other is a `map<int, int>` so in the first case I want to act on `*it` and in the second on `it->first` (where `it` is a const_iterator.)

Importantly, I want to do this as the collections are quite large and I don't want to have to simply create a `set` from the `map` just so I can deal with only one specific type.

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// General case for obtaining from, say, a set.
template< typename T >
const typename T::key_type getKey( const typename T::const_iterator& it )
{
    return *it;
}

// Specific case for a map<int,int>
template<>
const map<int, int>::key_type getKey< map<int, int> >( const map<int, int>::const_iterator& it )
{
    return it->first;
}

template< typename T >
void dumpOut( T& coll )
{
    for ( typename T::const_iterator it = coll.begin(); it != coll.end(); ++it )
    {
        const typename T::key_type& a = getKey<T>(it);
        cout << a << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    set<int> s1;
    s1.insert(10);
    s1.insert(15);
    s1.insert(20);

    dumpOut< set<int> >( s1 );

    map<int, int> m1;
    m1.insert( pair<int, int>(11, -1) );
    m1.insert( pair<int, int>(16, -1) );
    m1.insert( pair<int, int>(21, -1) );

    dumpOut< map<int, int> >( m1 );

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to make the specialised case for `map<int,int>` a little more general since the approach would clearly work for `map` generally, regardless of what the key and value actually are.

Any pointer (no pun intended) would be useful. Please note that I can't use C++11 solutions although I'm interested in solutions using it from an academic perspective. Thanks.

Comment: Not all collections have key_types, so I don see how this can be done generically.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sorry, you are right. What I really meant was *associative* collections. By *generic*, I really meant "generic enough for my case" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one C++ language problem here - partial specialization of functions is not allowed.
So it cannot be as simple as this:

```
// Specific case for a map<int,***>
template<typename Value_, typename Comp_, typename Alloc_>
const typename map<int, Value_, Comp_, Alloc_>::key_type getKey< map<int, Value_, Comp_, Alloc_> >( const typename map<int, Value_, Comp_, Alloc_>::const_iterator& it )
{
    return it->first;
}
```

Fortunately partial specialization of classes is allowed - so change to this way:

```
// work - for let say - sets
template <class Type_>
struct Key { 
   Key(typename Type_::const_iterator it) : value(*it) {}
   typename Type_::key_type value;
};

// work - for map<***>
template <class Key_, class Value_, class Comp_, class Alloc_>
struct Key<map<Key_, Value_,Comp_,Alloc_> > { 
   typedef map<Key_, Value_,Comp_,Alloc_> Type_;
   Key(typename Type_::const_iterator it) : value(it->first) {}
   typename Type_::key_type value;
};


template< typename T >
const typename T::key_type getKey( const typename T::const_iterator& it )
{
    return Key<T>(it).value;
}
```

I copied your changed example there: http://ideone.com/tE2aC

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a Traits that can be externally defined. You also want it to try to extract the key_type if present adn fall to a defautl case if not ( default cases than can later be specialized). This require a snap of SFINAE and template magic :

```
//// This is a SFINAE context enabler. If T is defined R is returned
template<class T, class R=void> struct enable_if_type
{
   typedef R type;
};

//// Default case is undefined as you want to get an error if you try to get a key_type from something that has none
template<class T, class Enable=void> struct key_type_of;


//// If T::key_type is a valid expression, extract it
template<class T>
struct key_type_of< T
                  , typename enable_if_type< typename T::key_type>::type
                  >
{
  typedef typename T::key_type type;
};
```

Now any type with a key_type typedef will use it, other will not compile BUT you can use 
a specialisation of key_type_of to provide it a successful match.

Example:

http://ideone.com/3PxJm

Once this is done, you can actually use it to get the key_type. To extract the key itself in a container independant way, you can make an external key_of function that you can generalize for broad type of collection.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty clever but I'm not sure that it's of use to me in my own situation. I already can get the key_type in the two instances that are of interest to me and I am interested in making an approach that replaced the specialised case for `map<int,int>` with a more general case for `map<K,V>`